# Site gallery breaks with flexbox in IE11

Tags: html, sass, internet-explorer-11, flexbox

On my current website, the responsive gallery at the top of [the home page](http://www.jameswebdevelopment.com) works great on all browsers but IE. I am looking at it in IE11, and it breaks the flexbox. I'm using Autoprefixer to add the needed prefixes for Flexbox, but it still seems to be breaking. I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
<section class="current-project">
  <div class="big-photo">
    <img src="http://www.jameswebdevelopment.com/codepen/flexbox-image-gallery/sfys-main.jpg" alt="Sing For Your Seniors performing at the Village Adult Day Health Center in New York City">
  </div>
  <section class="description">
    <div>
      <h1>Current Project</h1>
      <h2><a href="/work/sfys.php">Sing For Your Seniors</a></h2>
      <p>Sing For Your Seniors is a non-profit organization that uses music to change lives.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="minipics">
    <div>
      <img src="/img/work/sfys/logo.png" alt="Sing For Your Seniors logo">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="/img/work/sfys/home.png" alt="Sing For Your Seniors home page">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="/img/work/sfys/performers.png" alt="Sing For Your Seniors Performers page">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="/img/work/sfys/contact.png" alt="Sing For Your Seniors Contact page">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And the SCSS:

```
@mixin smallpics($grow: 1, $width: 50%) {
  flex: $grow $width;
}

.current-project, .project, .description {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.project {
  margin-bottom: ($padding * 2);
}

.description {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: ($padding * 2) $padding;
  @media all and (min-width: $small) {
    padding: 0 $padding;
  }
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a very good description of the problem.  What doesn't work?

Comment: @cimmanon I have it set up so that at different breakpoints the squares that make up the gallery shift. When it is on small screens, it only shows the main photo on top of the description. On medium screens, it shows the main photo on the left and the description on the right. On large screens, it shows the main photo on the left, the description in the middle, and four small photos in a 2x2 grid on the right. All done using flexbox. Works great on all browsers but IE. Sorry for the previous lack of description.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had to add a media query:

```
.current-project, .project, .description {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  @media all and (min-width: $small) {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears flex is broken in IE11.

I fix it by targeting IE11 like this:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   .content {
      flex: none;
    }
}
```